# Generate random polynomials with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, polynomials

I want to generate random binary polynomials with parameters `(n,m)`.

n is the number of polynomials to be generated 
and m is the number of elements of each polynomials.

At the same time I need it's polynomial to be unique.
And I also need to exclude the result with all elements equal to zero.

For example for `n=3` and `m=3` I am looking for something like
`[1 0 1] [1 0 0] [1 1 1]`.

Is there any command in mat lab which I can use to have the above results?? I would also like to avoid the for loop if possible!!

EDIT: I found that the command `unique(rand(n,m)>=0.5,'rows')` will do the job. But this does not guarantee that the result `[0 0 0]` will be excluded

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your polynoms could be interpreted as a binary number between 1 and 2^m-1.

```
%get a random subset of size n
X=randperm(2^m-1,n);
%convert it to a matrix
X=dec2bin(X)-'0';
```

Comment: @Hao Zhu: I saw your suggested edit, it's definitely an improvement to the code. For such improvements please write a comment or write your own answer, edits are intended for formatting errors, typos, broken links etc...