# Generate random linearly independent polynomials on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, polynomial-math, polynomials

I would like to create a set of K random linearly independent polynomials of M-th order on MATLAB. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356496/generate-random-polynomials-with-matlab) on StackOverflow but I am not sure of its linear independence; and I am not looking to make it binary as mentioned in the referred question.

I tried using:

> P = rand(K,M);

Will this give me K random linearly independent polynomials of M-th order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the numerical properties of the orthogonal decomposition matrices for linear independence.

```
m = 10;
F = rand(m);
F = F + F'; 
[Q,~] = qr(F);
P = Q'*diag(rand(1,m))*Q;
```

Comment: thank you @percusse. Does that mean P = rand(K,M); is not entirely correct?

Comment: @arvindrajan92 It would work most of the time but not guaranteed to be linearly independent (at the very least doesn't avoid being almost dependent)

Comment: @arvindrajan92 My pleasure.